# why angular makes http request to https://localhost:4200 instead of http://localhost:5001 to get data from Restful Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using angular version 15.0, and everything is gone well in backend.
but in frontend side, when the service requests to get data, unfortunately, an error is rised a bellow:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

because the request URL is:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/commodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes
```

other side, when we use Swagger with this URL:

https://localhost:5001/api/CommodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes
data is fetched successfully.

the service code is:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommodityTypesService {

  private baseUrl = 'api/commodityTypes';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /** GET all commodityTypes from the server */
  getAllCommodityTypes(): Observable<CommodityType[]> {
    return this.http.get<CommodityType[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getAllCommodityTypes/');
  }
  
  // rest of code ...
  }
```

and the error is:

```js
HttpErrorResponse
error: 
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /api/commodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes/</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
headers: 
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: 
"Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/commodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes/: 404 Not Found"
name: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok: 
false
status: 
404
statusText: 
"Not Found"
url: 
"http://localhost:4200/api/commodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes/"
[[Prototype]]: 
HttpResponseBase
```

how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should adjust your baseUrl:

```
export class CommodityTypesService {

  private baseUrl = https://localhost:5001/api/CommodityTypes;
```

**How to eliminate your CORS Error:**

You have to enable CORS **in your backend** for requests coming from localhost:4200.
In the **Startup.cs** of your backend, you could try to include the code of the accepted answer of the following thread (for me it worked):

[Angular 9 and .NET Core - access from origin localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165649/angular-9-and-net-core-access-from-origin-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by)

Please also note that `app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");` must be located on the top of the others middlewares.

Comment: I tested this scenario before, this time I also got the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/api/commodityTypes/getAllCommodityTypes/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Is there a special configuration required?

Comment: ASP.net core 5.

Comment: I now updated my answer with a link to a stackoverflow-page that explains what you have to configure in `Startup.cs` of your backend.

Comment: you are great...